# Makefile, better understanding rules

Tags: c, linux, makefile, gnu-make

Reading the [official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Introduction.html#Rule-Introduction)

> A prerequisite is a file that is used as input to create the target. A
>   target often depends on several files.

If my source file already includes the header, should I list the header in the rule?

**src.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myheader.h"

int main()
{
    printMessage();
    return 0;
}
```

**myheader.h**

```
void printMessage()
{
    printf("a message to screen\n");
}
```

**makefile**

```
src : src.o
    cc -o src src.o

src.o : src.c
    cc -c src.c
```

If I add `myheader.h` in the prerequisite it changes nothing, the same message is printed to screen. If a header is explicitly included, should it appear in the prerequisite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should.

The make program uses the list of files to figure out if a dependency changed and the the target should be rebuilt as a result. It needs you to specify that dependency explicitly.

It does not see the inclusion, it only sees the rules you specified. So there is a theoretical possibility that you change the header in a way that may require a  re-compilation of `src.o`, but `make` will not know you did that unless you tell it to watch out.

Comment: If header file A is including different header file B, and the `.c` is including the `A.h`, should I specify `B.h` too incase `B.h` changes? or would specifying `A.h` alone be enough?

Comment: @TonyTannous - Personally I'd prefer to have `A.h` as a dummy target that depend on `B.h` (by dummy I mean, it doesn't execute anything, only lists dependencies). This is where managing a makefile can become difficult, and a tool like CMake becomes useful.

Comment: I couldn't fine any paper or a proper article when to write my own make files or to use cmake. I have 4 projects which include quite few source files and header files. If you have any source to read I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @TonyTannous - Writing those things is in part art form. It's hard to figure out what's best until after you went past the learning curve. What helped me upon starting is [Mastering Cmake (Amazon link)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Mastering-CMake-Ken-Martin/dp/1930934319), and the official cmake tutorial/reference. The `verbose` option for `cmake` also helped me figure out where I was bungling it up.

Comment: Hi there, can't ask this directly on SO but I respect your opinion so asking in a comment. How would you recommend for a C programmer to learn c++ and then moving to c++14 things? to start immediately in c++14 or learn basics of c++ first?

Comment: @TonyTannous - Starting out from C++14 is not a bad idea, might as well get accustomed to current code. The biggest challenge is getting into the mindset of C++. I started out as a C programmer myself. I think [books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) are actually the best way to get up to speed on that. Bjarne's *A Tour of C++* is a good place to start. Then the "Effective C++" series is a must, the advice there is always relevant. And then just code, but I don't need to tell you that :)

Comment: Thanks! I will try to learn as much as possible in the next 2 weeks and then jump in deep water.

Answer (score 3):

The header file should be included in the dependency list.

The first time you use `make` to build your program, it will compile just the same whether you include `myheader.h` as a dependency or not.  The difference is what happens when one of the files changes.

If you run `make` again without changing anything, it will say that "src" is up to date and won't compile anything.  However, if you were to modify `myheader.h` and you *didn't* include it as a dependency, then `make` will say that the target is up to date.  It doesn't look at the source file to see what files it includes.  The `make` utility doesn't know anything about C or C++ source code (or any other source code).  It looks **only** at whether the given files have changes without looking at their content.

When you include `myheader.h` as a dependency, if you later modify that file then running `make` will rebuild the program.

If you want to know all the non-system header files that a given source file depends on, you can run gcc with the `-MM` option.  This will output a make rule listing the header dependencies of a source file.

For example, if you run `gcc -MM src.c`, you'll get the following output:

```
src.o: src.c myheader.h
```

You can then include that in your makefile.

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well. I've read it and gave it an upvote.